# Por que preciso do './' para executar comandos no Unix?

Tags: windows, linha-de-comando, unix

Notei que todo executável que eu gero eu preciso por um `./` para o executar, tanto no Linux quanto no MacOS (sistemas Unix/Unix-*like*). Por exemplo, para compilar um arquivo C com o GCC e executá-lo logo em seguida, faço os seguintes comandos:

```
$ gcc fonte.c
$ ./a.out
```

Isso também se aplica quando eu crio um shell script:

```
$ vim script.sh
$ chmod u+x script.sh
$ ./script.sh
```

Em compensação, quando faço no Windows, não preciso por o `./` na frente. Por exemplo, se eu criar um `bat`, na pasta `exemplo`, basta chamar o `cmd` e executar o script diretamente:

```
$ cd exemplo
$ script.bat
```

Até mesmo quando eu uso o MingW (como o `git bash` fornecido pelo SourceTree), que é um ambiente mais "unixado" dentro do Windows, eu também não preciso do `./`. Pegando o mesmo exemplo da geração do shell script no Linux, no `git bash` seria assim:

```
$ vim script.sh
$ script.sh
```

### Dúvidas

1. Por que nos sistemas mais Unix eu preciso por esse `./` para executar meus executáveis no diretório de trabalho atual?
2. Por que no Windows eu não ponho o `./`? (Nem o equivalente `.\` na notação de separador de diretórios Windows?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa porque o diretório atual não está no *PATH*. O Linux/Unix sempre procura na variável de ambiente $PATH. <strike>Já o Windows tem um comportamento: se não estiver no *PATH*, procura no diretório corrente, por isso você não precisa colocar o diretório antes do executável.</strike>

O Windows faz a busca de uma maneira diferente. Após separar o comando dos argumentos e resolver as variáveis de ambiente, seguem-se os seguintes passos:

1. caso não for passado um diretório, procura se é um comando interno do shell. Caso encontre algum, executa o comando. Caso contrário, vai para 2;
2. caso for passado um diretório, será executado o executável do diretório. Caso contrário, retornará erro ao usuário;
3. caso não for passado um diretório, será executado o comando do diretório corrente;
4. por fim, será procurado no `%PATH%`.

fonte: [Technet Windows NT- 
Command Search Sequence](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120)

Se isso te incomoda no Linux/Unix, basta adicionar `PATH=$PATH:.` no arquivo que inicializa suas variáveis de ambiente. E nunca mais precisará de `./` para rodar executáveis.

Vou deixar o comentário do arquivo `/etc/profile.d/z-dot-in-non-root-path.sh` do Slackware Current, porque tem uma explicação interessante para isso.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Traditionally Slackware has included '.' at the end of the non-root
# $PATH, and kept this behavior long after it had been dropped elsewhere
# due to the relatively low attack risk by having it at (or near) the
# end of the $PATH.  But times have changed, and having this as a default
# violates POLA (principle of least astonishment) just like removing it
# back in the early 90s would have.  So, by default this script is not
# enabled.  If you'd like '.' back at the end of your $PATH for non-root
# users systemwide, make this script executable.  A better choice is
# probably to leave it off and let individual users decide to add it
# in their local profile scripts if they want it.  Even better is just
# to start programs in '.' with ./program, like most of us have been
# doing for years.

# For non-root users, add the current directory to the search path:
if [ ! "`id -u`" = "0" ]; then
 PATH="$PATH:."
fi
```

Em resumo, essa prática viola o [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) na visão dos desenvolvedores do Slackware.

Comment: Como o @lazyFox diz num comentário em outra resposta, na verdade o Windows verifica *primeiro* no diretório atual, e *depois* tenta os diretórios na variável `%PATH%`, em ordem, caso não encontre um executável no diretório corrente.

Comment: Obrigado @Wtrmute.

Answer (score 5):

Em primeiro lugar esse `./` é colocado atrás do nome do seu executável para garantir que você está a executar o mesmo dentro do directório actual.

Em segundo lugar trata-se de um método de segurança para impedir de executar algum programa/script prejudicial que se tenha alojado no directório actual. Se não existisse a necessidade de colocar `./` seria possível colocar scripts maliciosos dentro de um directório com as seguintes designações `ls` `nano` `vim` `ps` entre outros, e quando fosse a executar `ps` por exemplo poderia estar a executar um comando completamente diferente do qual não saberia o seu output.

Penso que basicamente é isto, mas fico a aguardar mais respostas.

Comment: Tá no caminho :) Sobre o segundo ponto da pergunta, tem alguma coisa a falar? Ou a MS deixou uma falha sem querer e está mantendo por retrocompatibilidade? XD

Comment: Penso que o windows faz a "pesquisa" no directório actual e só depois vai verificar a variável do sistema "PATH". Mas como nunca gostei do shell do windows, nunca me interessei muito, mas estou curioso para saber se existe algum motivo específico.

Comment: É por compatibilidade com o DOS, que nos tempos do disco flexível não tinha variável `%PATH%` — sem discos rígidos, não faz sentido estabelecer uma lista de diretórios para procurar executáveis. A semântica foi sendo herdada de versão para versão até chegarmos aqui.

Comment: Interessante essa visao voltada para segurança