# Como rodar um arquivo bash "mytest.sh" em um MAC sem usar "./", usando alias e de maneira global?

Tags: linux, bash

Eu tenho um arquivo `mytest.sh` que será distribuído entre outros usuários (todos com mac). Queria saber o que tem que ser feito para que eles possam rodar o script desse arquivo, de qualquer lugar ( de maneira global ) sem ter que usar `./` e suando somente uma alias, `runtest` ?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216827/64969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem duas alternativas.

**Primeira:**
Adicionar o diretório que está localizado seu script na variável PATH para facilitar a execução

```
PATH=$PATH:~/opt/bin:~/dev/bin:/seu/diretorio/
```

Sendo assim você precisará apenas digitar o nome do seu script de qualquer diretório que estiver.

**Segunda:**
Criar um álias, como vc mesmo sugeriu.

```
alias NomeDoAlias='/seu/diretorio/script.sh'
```

Desse modo será necessário digitar na linha de comando apenas o Nome do seu Álias.

Os dois comandos podem ser adicionados no arquivo */etc/profile* , pois todo usuário que logar ja irá carregar tais configurações.

Comment: a primeira é uma boa opção.

Comment: Eu acho que na primeira opção você não deveria por o `script.sh` no final da variável `$PATH`

Comment: Realmente @JeffersonQuesado, obrigado pela análise. A variável PATH deve conter o diretório em que o script está localizado, sendo assim, todos os scripts daquele diretório estarão automaticamente na PATH. A resposta foi atualizada.

Comment: @JJoao foi somente pra dar melhor entendimento como é acrescentado diretórios a variável PATH.

Comment: @Diego, ok, estou a ver a ideia. Não é relevante mas na tradição unixeira, `/dev/` costuma ser para devices e não costuma haver lá bin, e as /opt/... não costumam estar nas áreas dos utilizadores.

Answer (score 1):

Vejo aqui duas questões ortogonais:

- **para ter uso fácil de uma script**, recomendaria instalar a script numa pasta do PATH (exemplo `sudo cp script /usr/local/bin` para uso geral; ou `cp script ~/bin` para uso pessoal)
- **para evitar o `./...`**, podemos juntar a pasta actual 
  ao PATH

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

(eventualmente juntar esta linha ao ficheiro `~/.bashrc` para que seja activada cada vez que entramos)

A segunda opção é ótima para máquina pessoais mas deve ser evitada se trabalharmos numa máquina hostil (exemplo se formos administrador 
de sistema com utilizadores que gostem de tentar armadilhar comandos...)